# How to strengthen my ankle after an injury?

Tags: exercise, injury, injury-prevention

I sprained my ankle a couple years ago. Nowadays, if I do hard physical exercises continuously for a couple of days, it bungs and my ligaments start to hurt and I cannot encumber it. It usually occurs after some wrong ground contacts/touch-downs.

Can you give some exercises to strengthen it?

Comment: Have you seen your doctor about this?

Comment: Thanks for the link @Sean Duggan it contains good information however my problem isn't so serious. No I haven't been to my doctor.

Answer (score 0):

"Dogen's Titanium Ankles" - an excellent program designed for ankle injury prevention under extreme load:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8B1XvEbJUKE
Source 2: http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2oqcyn

This is pretty much the authoritative source on preventing ankle injury. Also, lots of calf raises with weight. Obviously progressing from no weight / with assistance, etc, since you were injured.

Comment: Unfortunately the video you linked in cannot be played in my country..

Comment: I added another link. If it doesn't work, search please.